# Stop Spring Boot tests from reaching out to authentication provider

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, spring-security, spring-test

I'm using spring boot for dependency injection and am running into `Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: Read timed out` exceptions occasionally when running tests. In most of my tests, I don't actually care about authorization and would like to not make a network call if possible. I would still like to use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation to construct my services.

I've tried `@MockBean(JwtDecoder.class)` but still see test flakes. How can I prevent spring from trying to contact my JWT provider in my tests?

EDIT:

I've got an annotation I'm using to mark all my test classes that looks like this:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@MockBean(JwtDecoder.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(
    exclude = {
      OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration.class,
      OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration.class,
      SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
    })
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SpringTest {}
```

EDIT 2:

Stacktrace with some of the bits ellipses'd out:

```
<TestClass> > test() FAILED
    org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter [Class] in constructor [Classes in test constructor]: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        ...

        Caused by:
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
            ...

            Caused by:
            org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is ...
                ...

                Caused by:
                org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is ...
                    ...

                    Caused by:
                    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtDecoder' defined in class path resource [Class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and has a JwtDecoder bean]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is ...
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:233)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1234)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
                        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
                        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer$JwtConfigurer.getJwtDecoder(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java:405)
                        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer$JwtConfigurer.getAuthenticationProvider(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java:414)
                        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.getAuthenticationProvider(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java:321)
                        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.init(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java:240)
                        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.init(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java:140)
                        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:338)
                        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:300)
                        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38)
                        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:285)
                        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:83)
                        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:305)
                        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38)
                        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:127)
                        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
                        ... 102 more

                        Caused by:
                        org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder]: Factory method 'jwtDecoder' threw exception; nested exception is ...
                            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
                            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
                            ... 135 more

                            Caused by:
                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: Read timed out
                                at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getSignatureAlgorithms(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:107)
                                at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoders.withProviderConfiguration(JwtDecoders.java:122)
                                at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(JwtDecoders.java:66)
                                at <Class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and has a JwtDecoder bean>
                                ...
                                at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
                                at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
                                ...
                                ... 136 more

                                Caused by:
                                com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: Read timed out
                                    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.updateJWKSetFromURL(RemoteJWKSet.java:167)
                                    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.get(RemoteJWKSet.java:260)
                                    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getSignatureAlgorithms(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:90)
                                    ... 149 more

                                    Caused by:
                                    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
                                        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
                                        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
                                        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
                                        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
                                        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
                                        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
                                        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
                                        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1364)
                                        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
                                        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
                                        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292)
                                        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
                                        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:754)
                                        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
                                        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
                                        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
                                        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
                                        at com.nimbusds.jose.util.DefaultResourceRetriever.getInputStream(DefaultResourceRetriever.java:305)
                                        at com.nimbusds.jose.util.DefaultResourceRetriever.retrieveResource(DefaultResourceRetriever.java:257)
                                        at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.updateJWKSetFromURL(RemoteJWKSet.java:165)
                                        ... 151 more
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't actually care about authorization and would like to not make a
> network call if possible

Do you mean that you want to disable all the spring-security  stuff ? If yes, one quick thing that you can try is to disable all the auto configurations related to spring-security using `@EnableAutoConfiguration` :

```java
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class , OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration.class,OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration.class})
public class FooTest{

}
```

Comment: EDIT: updated my question with my test annotation (because comments don't format code well). I'm still getting timeouts excluding these classes.

Comment: post the exception . i just give you a general idea without the detailed information .

Comment: I appreciate the support. Just update the question with a scrubbed stacktrace. These are deeply nested exceptions and my intuition is that only the last few exceptions matter. If you need something that I ellipses'd out, I can add it in. I'm starting to suspect that I've got a `@Component` on the class path that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, and it both provides the JwtDecoder bean as well as overrides the `configure(HttpSecurity)` method, and that it may be part of the problem.